# Changing scope of many Spring beans during tests

Tags: java, spring, testing

I'm running tests using spring (SpringJUnit4ClassRunner and @ContextConfiguration). The tests are run in parallel.
Some of my beans are singleton, and I would like to change them to be in scope "thread" of the tests. I want each test to have its own instance of the bean.

I've managed to it by having an applicationContext.xml file and a applicationTestContext.xml file which is used for tests.
In the applicationTestContext.xml I define those beans with scope "thread".

The problem with this is that everytime we add a new bean of that type, we'll have to add it to both applicationContext.xml and applicationTestContext.xml which is pretty annoying.
Is there a way to do it with less boilerplate?

Comment: Is your app a single-thread application? If not, the beans are also used in parallel in your app, and should thus be able to be used in parallel in your tests as well. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The tests reset the bean's state on setUp and tearDown. This is useful for testing, but not something that happens in the app. This is why I don't want the tests to share the same instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gather up all the beans whose scope you want to customize and put them in a separate bean config file, included from both `applicationContext` and `applicationTestContext`, e.g.

```
<import resource="customScopedBeans.xml"/>
```

Then use a placeholder for the scope

```
<bean class="com.Foo" scope="${threadOrSingleton}" />
```

and declare the property differently in the parent config file.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="properties">
      <value>threadOrSingleton=thread</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```